# Callback for GtkSwitch is seg-faulting when accessing passed data

Tags: gtk, glade

I put a GtkSwitch in my Glade UI file (it targets GTK-3.24 with no warnings) and pass as an argument a struct containing some data. The signal is `on_switch1_state_set`.

main.h contains:

```
typedef struct _MyData MyData;
struct _MyData {
  GtkWidget *switch1;
  int value;
}

int on_switch1_state_set (GtkSwitch *, MyData *);
```

main.c contains:

```
data->switch1 = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "switch1"));
data->value = 0;
```

callbacks.c contains:

```
int on_switch1_state_set (GtkSwitch *switch1, MyData *data) {

  fprintf (stdout, "%i\n", data->value);
  
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

For some reason this seg-faults on the fprintf and I don't know why. I interpret this to mean the pointer to the struct has been corrupted somehow. It's happy if in the callback I only do, say:

```
  fprintf (stdout, "Dave\n");
```

but of course that isn't accessing my data struct. I have many other callbacks in this program with signals from entries, checkbuttons, radiobuttons, spinbuttons, etc. and they all have no problem manipulating data from the struct. It's only the switch that presents an issue.

Why does accessing the struct cause a seg-fault in the GtkSwitch callback?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the [GTK 3 documentation for the `GtkSwitch` signal](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/signal.Switch.state-set.html).

There are actually three arguments (not two, as I had):

```
gboolean
state_set (
  GtkSwitch* self,
  gboolean state,
  gpointer user_data
)
```

I was missing the `gboolean state` argument.

After adding that, it works perfectly.